# Codeigniter dynamic routing (or loading one controller using different urls from db)

Tags: php, codeigniter, dynamic, routes

I have the following problem, I get urls like domain.com/en/contact or domain.com/de/kontakt.
I would like for both to point to the controller contact.php.

At the moment I am using the follwoing code:

> $route['(\w{2})/(\w{2})/contact/?(.*)?'] = 'contact';
>
> $route['(\w{2})/(\w{2})/kontakt/?(.*)?'] = 'contact';

I would rather have it like this.

> fn get_type()
> {
> gets pages and the type (indicating contoller e.g. contact)
> }
>
> $type = get_type($param = ...);
>
> load_controller($type); // loads controller from within base controller

So I know this is not correct codeigniter syntax, I would rather not use libraries and clutter my library directory with libraries like thoses.

Does anyone have a good idea for this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get dynamic routing to work I now do the following.

The CMS writes a file into the codeigniter config dir, lets call it `dynamic_route.php`
The written file is analog to the normale route.php config file.

An writes stuff like

```
$route['(\w{2})/(\w{2})/URL_PART_FROM_CMS/?(.)?'] = 'CONTROLLER_CHOSEN_IN_CMS';
```

This file is included into the routs.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "content";
$route['404_override'] = '';
// include file
include('dynamic_routes.php');
```

Every time the cms changes sth. the dynamic file is rewritten. This makes it very dynamic without any performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [remapping](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping) the method being passed instead of using routes:

```
function index(){
    // my default method
}
function _remap($method){
    if ($method == 'en'){
        $this->english();
    } else if($method == 'de') {
        $this->german();
    } else {
        $this->index();
    }
}

function english(){
    // my english method
}

function german(){
    // my german method
}
```

Comment: Well, the problem is, as far as I understand it, this will not give me different controllers, right? I would rather have it, that if I go to domain.com/kontakt or /contact I get to the same controller. The remapping only works inside a function, right? Any other suggestions?

Comment: remapping only works inside of the same controller, yeah. it also looks like you may an extra node in your route definition since you don't have to account for the domain in routes: $route['(\w{2})/contact/?(.)?'] = 'contact';
$route['(\w{2})/kontakt/?(.)?'] = 'contact';

Comment: Well, no that is actually for the language part, my url goes like this. domain.com/en/contact. So any other ideas to get something like this working?

Comment: you shouldn't be putting your domain in the route - $route['([a-z]{2})/contact'] = 'contact' and $route['([a-z]{2})/kontakt'] = 'contact';

Comment: it is not the domain, it is the language part. Why would I not use it in the route so it is ignored? I do not see the reason this.

Comment: $route['(\w{2})/(\w{2})/contact/?(.)?'] = 'contact'; comes out to
first/second/contact/makes-contact-optional-huh whereas you should be doing $route['([a-z]{2})/contact'] = 'contact'; which works out to
en/contact   ... you have 2 instances of (\w{2}) in your route - it's not needed